# Simple sentiment analysis model gives stupid accuracy

Tags: pytorch, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a sentiment analysis model from scratch but I ran into issues so thought I'd implement one using pytorch and then replicate but I also ran into issues with the pytorch version.

I'm not sure the outputs are correct and apparently the accuracy is around 110%.....
I'm not sure i am doing this right. Heck I'm not even sure what I'm doing.

Please help
Here's the code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# This file contains the same model i wrote manually in the other file but using pytorch in order for me to understand where i am going wrong with the manual model

class SentimentAnalysisModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(10000, embedding_dim)
        # embedding layer takes in a tensor of size (batch_size, sequence_length) and outputs a tensor of size (batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim)
        # this layer is responsible for converting the input text into a vector of size (embedding_dim)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dim, out_channels=hidden_dim, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dim, out_channels=hidden_dim, kernel_size=3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, text):
        # the forward method takes in a tensor of size (batch_size, sequence_length) and outputs a tensor of size (batch_size, output_dim)
        embedding = self.embedding(text)
        embedding = embedding.permute(0, 2, 1)
        conv1 = self.conv1(embedding)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        pooled = self.pool(conv2)
        pooled = pooled.permute(0, 2, 1)
        # permute is responsible for changing the shape of the tensor. In this case, it changes the shape from (batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim) to (batch_size, embedding_dim, sequence_length)
        dense = self.fc(pooled)
        return dense
    
    def train(self, X, labels, num_epochs, batch_size):
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for batch in range(0, len(X), batch_size):
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                inputs = torch.tensor(X[batch:batch+batch_size], dtype=torch.long)
                targets = labels[batch:batch+batch_size]
                outputs = self.forward(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                print("loss: ", loss.item())

    def predict(self, X):
        X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.long)
        outputs = self.forward(X)
        outputs = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        # print("probabilities: ", outputs)
        return outputs

    def evaluate(self, X, labels):
        X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.long)
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        outputs = self.forward(X)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        # torch.max returns the maximum value in each row of the tensor and the index of that value
        # the second arg is for 
        correct = (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        print("correct: ", correct)
        print("total: ", len(labels))
        print("accuracy: ", correct/len(labels))


pd = pd.read_csv("Dataset/dataset.csv")
pd = pd[:100]
X = pd[pd['Language'] == 'en']['Text']
labels = pd[pd['Language'] == 'en']['Label']

# preprocessing the data manually using keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from preprocess import preprocess_labels

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=100)
labels = preprocess_labels(labels)
print('labels before to_categorical: ', labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=4)



model = SentimentAnalysisModel(10, 10, 4)
model.train(X, labels, 20, 32)
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.evaluate(X, labels)
```

And here's the kind of output I am getting:

```
$ python pytorch_test.py
2023-08-19 19:04:51.330975: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2023-08-19 19:04:51.331083: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
labels before to_categorical:  [3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0]
loss:  3.8897905349731445
loss:  3.8837969303131104
loss:  3.879756212234497
loss:  3.873053550720215
loss:  3.8692281246185303
loss:  3.8650543689727783
loss:  3.8564913272857666
loss:  3.854645252227783
loss:  3.85028076171875
loss:  3.83972430229187
loss:  3.8397984504699707
loss:  3.8351874351501465
loss:  3.8224565982818604
loss:  3.8244481086730957
loss:  3.8195455074310303
loss:  3.8044466972351074
loss:  3.808379888534546
loss:  3.8031580448150635
loss:  3.7855300903320312
loss:  3.791482448577881
loss:  3.7859227657318115
loss:  3.7656538486480713
loss:  3.7737011909484863
loss:  3.7678332328796387
loss:  3.744844913482666
loss:  3.7550785541534424
loss:  3.7489407062530518
loss:  3.7232182025909424
loss:  3.735753297805786
loss:  3.7294199466705322
loss:  3.701007843017578
loss:  3.7159347534179688
loss:  3.7095091342926025
loss:  3.6785190105438232
loss:  3.695913314819336
loss:  3.6895029544830322
loss:  3.6561203002929688
loss:  3.676055431365967
loss:  3.6697707176208496
loss:  3.6342666149139404
loss:  3.656748056411743
loss:  3.6507418155670166
loss:  3.613410472869873
loss:  3.6384010314941406
loss:  3.6327908039093018
loss:  3.593982219696045
loss:  3.6213669776916504
loss:  3.6162688732147217
loss:  3.5763375759124756
loss:  3.605937957763672
loss:  3.6014351844787598
loss:  3.5607175827026367
loss:  3.5923080444335938
loss:  3.588432788848877
loss:  3.5472371578216553
loss:  3.58054780960083
loss:  3.577294111251831
loss:  3.535857915878296
loss:  3.5706052780151367
loss:  3.5679421424865723
correct:  243
total:  92
accuracy:  2.641304347826087
(tf)
```

So as you can see I am not training it heavily right now because there's no point but the loss is decreasing steadily but the accuracy is 264%

Thanks a bunch for reading thus far. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Step through the `evaluate` function; what are the shape of `outputs`,  `predicted`, `labels`?